# --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert and retrieve image data from SQLite Database.
I have the following codes. Image is inserted correctly but when I try to retrieve, Logcat shows  --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null error. Please help me

This class is used to create and insert database

```
    ImageView img;
    String picpath;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Canvas cnvs;
    Random r;
    int x, y, height, width;
    ByteArrayOutputStream blob;
    //SQL sql;
    Paint paint;
    String name, no;
    Uri data;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    ;
    Cursor cur;
    TextView txt;
    int colIndex;
    ContentValues ctv;
    byte[] imgData;


    public static final String DB_NAME = "New.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Sample";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String NAME = "Name";
    public static final String NO = "No";
    public static final String IMG = "Img";
    public static final String PIXELX = "PosX";
    public static final String PIXELY = "PosY";

    public void create() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + NO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + IMG + " BLOB," + PIXELX + " INTEGER ," + PIXELY + " INTEGER );");
        db.close();
    }

    public void insert() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
        ctv.put(NAME, name);
        ctv.put(NO, no);
        try {
            FileInputStream img_file = new FileInputStream(picpath);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(img_file);
            imgData = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read();
            ctv.put(IMG, imgData);
            long val = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, ctv);
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (val < 0)
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Image not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bis.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        db.close();
    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);


        ctv = new ContentValues();
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        r = new Random();
        paint = new Paint();
        x = r.nextInt(100);
        blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        create();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        no = i.getStringExtra("no");
        //Open Button
        Button open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent gal_open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gal_open, 1);

            }
        });
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                cnvs = new Canvas(bmp);

                height = img.getMeasuredHeight();
                width = img.getMeasuredWidth();
                x = r.nextInt(height);
                y = r.nextInt(width);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);


                txt.setText(x + "," + y);
                cnvs.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath), 0, 0, null);
                cnvs.drawRect(x, y, x + 20, y + 20, paint);
                img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            }
        });


        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                create();
                insert();

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && intentData != null) {

            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            cnvs = new Canvas(bmp);
            height = img.getMeasuredHeight();
            width = img.getMeasuredWidth();
            x = r.nextInt(height);
            y = r.nextInt(width);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            data = intentData.getData();

            cur = getContentResolver().query(data, filePath, null, null, null);
            cur.moveToFirst();

            colIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            picpath = cur.getString(colIndex);
            cur.close();

            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt.setText(x + "," + y);
            cnvs.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath), 0, 0, null);
            cnvs.drawRect(x, y, x + 20, y + 20, paint);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
```

The code to retrieve data is

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    //SQL sql;
    User user;
    String name;
    TextView no;
    ImageView img;
    int imgx, imgy;
    View touchlistener;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    byte[] imgData1;
    Cursor cur;
    int pixelx, pixely;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "New.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Sample";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String NAME = "Name";
    public static final String NO = "No";
    public static final String IMG = "Img";
    public static final String PIXELX = "PosX";
    public static final String PIXELY = "PosY";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void retrieve() {
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        cur = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{NAME, NO, IMG, PIXELX, PIXELY}, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        imgData1 = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("Img"));
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData1, 0, imgData1.length));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Retreived", 100).show();
        cur.close();
        db.close();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        retrieve();
    }
}
```